# Implementing BFS in Java to find fastest way from number X to number Z

Tags: java, algorithm, search, breadth-first-search

**I am more than okay with non-BFS way.**

So let's say that the operations that I can do are

1. `x - 1`
2. `x / 3 (if x%3 == 0)`
3. `x / 5 (if x%5 == 0)`

And I want to find the fastest way to number Z by doing these operations.

Sadly I have no idea how to create this Queue, any ideas?

*Example*

```
x = 19;
y = 4;

BFS "level" 0 = 19 
BFS "level" 1 = 18 (x-1)
BFS "level" 2 = 17(18 - 1),
                6(18 / 3)
BFS "level" 3 = 16(17 - 1), 
                5(6 - 1), 
                2(6 / 3) - do not include, since 2 < y
BFS "level" 4 = ..., 4(5 - 1) ,.. 

Number y found in "level" 4
```

OR

Could it be done like this?

```
while array doesn't contain Y
 for int x: array
  if x%3 == 0
   add x/3 to array
  if x%5 == 0
   add x/5 to array
  add x-1 to array
  delete x from array
  level++
```

Comment: Could you add some explanations?

Comment: You have to find all possible ways or at least one? It looks similar to problem when when you have coins with some nominals x1 x2 xN and you have to collect sum X.

Comment: @brainless I have to find the shortest way.

Comment: In essence, you are looking at a tree, where the root node contains your `x` and each node in this tree contains 3 children. So what you are really doing is level order traversal of the tree until you reach the goal node which is your `z`. I hope that helps you get the bigger picture

Comment: @Smac89 I understand that. My problem is more syntax based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
static class Trace {
    public int currentValue;
    public LinkedList<Integer> path;

    public Trace(int val) { currentValue = val; path = new LinkedList<Integer>(); }
}

static void addToQueue(int value, Trace currentTrace, LinkedList<Trace> queue) {
    Trace nt = new Trace(value);
    nt.path = (LinkedList<Integer>)currentTrace.path.clone();
    nt.path.addLast(value);
    queue.addLast(nt);
}

static LinkedList<Integer> findPath(int from, int to) throws Exception {
    // Safety check
    if (from < to) throw new Exception("from < to");
    LinkedList<Trace> q = new LinkedList<Trace>();

    // Initialize queue with FROM value
    Trace t = new Trace(from);
    t.path.addLast(from);
    q.addLast(t);

    // Repeat till we have an answer
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
        Trace e = q.getFirst();
        q.removeFirst();
        int cv = e.currentValue;

        // Check if we have a solution 
        if (cv == to) return e.path;


        // Handle steps of -1, /3 and /5
        if (cv-1 >= to)
            addToQueue(cv-1, e, q);

        if (cv%3 == 0 && cv/3 >= to)
            addToQueue(cv/3, e, q);

        if (cv%5 == 0 && cv/5 >= to)
            addToQueue(cv/5, e, q);
    }

    // This will never execute because of existence of linear path
    // of length(levels) FROM - TO
    throw new Exception("no path");
}
```

There are two way this function will return.

One is when FROM is smaller than TO, but this is just a safety check.

The other way this returns is when currently examined value is equal to TO.

This solution base on the fact that BFS always finds the shortest path on uniform tree. But instead of building the entire tree we are creating the parts of the tree on the fly. You can imagine it in the way, that you are only looking on the part of the tree at given time and process it nodes.

You can also look on this problem from the other way.

**"How can I reach X value from Z value using +1 *3 and *5 operations"**

And code is simplest, and maybe compiler can optimize it. I will skip the comments because they will be similar to those in above code.

```
static void addToQueue2(int value, Trace currentTrace, LinkedList<Trace> queue) {
    Trace nt = new Trace(value);
    nt.path = (LinkedList<Integer>)currentTrace.path.clone();
    nt.path.addFirst(value);
    queue.addLast(nt);
}

static LinkedList<Integer> findPath2(int from, int to) throws Exception {
    if (from < to) throw new Exception("from < to");
    LinkedList<Trace> q = new LinkedList<Trace>();
    Trace t = new Trace(to);
    t.path.addFirst(to);
    q.addLast(t);

    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
        Trace e = q.getFirst();
        q.removeFirst();
        int cv = e.currentValue;
        if (cv == from) return e.path;
        if (cv > from) continue;

        addToQueue2(cv+1, e, q);
        addToQueue2(cv*3, e, q);
        addToQueue2(cv*5, e, q);
    }
    throw new Exception("no path");
}
```

There seems to be a way to do it much much faster but this is not BFS, and I don't have the proof to support this code (and it lacks, tracking and error checking, but that's simple to implement):

```
static int findPath3(long from, long to) {
    int len = 0;
    while (from != to) {
        if (from % 5 == 0 && from / 5 >= to) {
            from /= 5;
        } else if (from % 3 == 0 && from / 3 >= to) {
            from /= 3;
        } else {
            from--;
        }
        len++;
    }
    return len;
}
```

Comment: That looks great. One question. How could I find how many "levels"(as I shown in the example, I don't really know how to call them), did the program went through?

Comment: Number of levels = path.size()-1
The zero level is the case when from == to

Comment: You are gonna hate me right now. But where do I return it from?

Comment: @Seven check edits for comments and small explanation.

Comment: Great! Just an additional question, you don't have to answer it, but how could you theoretically speed this algorithm up for let"s say findPath(10^8, 1). Is it even possible to use this for such a big number?

Comment: Wow, nice. But what if I wanted to add `x+1` operation, it wouldn't be the fastest way then, correct? Seriously, you don't have to keep answering :D EDIT: if I wanted to have operations `x+1, x-1, x/2, x/3` then it wouldn't be the fastest way, right?

Comment: If you add `+1` operation then I don't think that there is a faster way than BFS (which might be expensive). The reason is that the new operation is not bringing you closer to the answer. Eg from=14, to=1. Without +1 operation it will take 6 levels(-1, -1, -1, /3, -1, /3), with +1 only 3 (+1, /5, /3). The `+1` brings this problem to Dijkstra shortest path where you have to keep track of more stuff, like, was this node visited.

Comment: Hmm.. That's what I thought, I'm still gonna try to adjust it for bigger numbers. Thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to build a tree (ternary in your case). Each node of tree should contain number and operation that was performed to get to this number. Leafs of the node are possible numbers for example if current node is 15 then leafs (<14, -1>, <5, /3>, <3, /5>), if 14 then only (<13, -1>). 
You can build this tree until reach Z, than try to find shortest way to Z in tree, there should be some algorithms for that.